# Which gsettings keys are modified when changing the color from the Appearance menu?

Tags: command-line, gnome, themes, 22.04, gsettings

I'm working on a shell script that simultaneously changes the theme and color palette of the system and some applications like guake. The script uses gsettings for the system theme and should be able to modify the colour of the accents like the Appearance menu in 22.04.

So far I've found the keys `gtk-theme` and `icon-theme` from the schema `org.gnome.desktop.interface` for changing some of the colours, as well as `org.gnome.shell.ubuntu color-scheme` for switching between light and dark themes.

Have I missed any keys that the Appearance menu sets and if so, is there a comprehensive list of those keys somewhere?

Comment: ^start from a fresh state, `dconf watch /` and then change the colour to see everything that's affected.

Comment: I think I figured it out already and left an answer below, but that's a super useful trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here as I think I found some sort of an answer by myself; after some digging on github for what changed when the accent colors were implemented, I came across [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/blob/0c37a22a128357f781e8766926daed53287dd244/CONTRIBUTING.md) on the Yaru theme repo.

It seems that

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Yaru
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound theme-name Yaru
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme Yaru
```

are the relevant commands for setting Yaru as your theme, so I'm assuming those are the only keys I should worry about.